# Underflow occurring in computation

Tags: plotting, numerics

I've got an "Underflow occurred in computation" problem.
Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
toplot = 
  Table[
    Exp[-((x - 1.21*10^15)^4/(2*10^25))],
    {x, 1.20*10^15, 1.22*10^15, 10^12}, {y, 1.20*10^15, 1.22*10^15, 10^12}];

ListDensityPlot[toplot, PlotRange -> All]
```

and the error is

> General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation. >>
>   ...
>   General::stop: Further output of General::unfl will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

When I replace the power 4 with the power 2 in the code as follows:

```
toplot = 
  Table[
    Exp[-((x - 1.21*10^15)^2/(2*10^25))],
    {x, 1.20*10^15, 1.22*10^15, 10^12}, {y, 1.20*10^15, 1.22*10^15, 10^12}];
```

the code works without any error and I get

```
ListDensityPlot[toplot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Unfortunately that's not the function I need :(

I found some other topics about the underflow problem, but I wasn't still able to fix my problem by just reading them.

Any help/suggestions to avoid/bypass the problem are welcome.

Comment: I suppose it's about numerical calculation error.

Comment: $MinNumber=6.229688249675322*10^-1355718576299610
It's quite small, that's why I'm surprised that the computation has an underflow, but I'm pretty far from being an expert...

Comment: You're getting underflow, but you're still getting a valid plot right?

Comment: yes, but it is a "flat" plot (it is all blue)..
Actually, I think that the numbers that I'm using are not correct and that it is not a mathematica's error...

Comment: Ponder this `Min@Table[-((x - 1.21*10^15)^4/(2*10^25)), {x, 1.20*10^15, 1.22*10^15,10^12}, {y, 1.20*10^15, 1.22*10^15, 10^12}]/Log[10]`, the exponent base 10 of your smallest number.

Comment: Why couldn't you rescale your units and avoid all this trouble?

Comment: @J. M.
I tried but it was still not working: in fact even if I scaled everything coherently, the result of the computation was again an underflow.

Now I'm pretty sure that the program was working properly, and that the numbers I was using in the Exp[...] were not correct: I tried with other values and the code was running well, so I just need to understand which are the correct values for my function.
Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty of doing numerical calculation with the 4th power as opposed to the square is immense. This easily demonstrated by doing a couple of exact computations.

```
With[{x = (12/10)*10^15}, Exp[-((x - (121/100)*10^15)^2/(2*10^25))]]
```

> `1/E^5`

```
With[{x = (12/10)*10^15}, Exp[-((x - (121/100)*10^15)^4/(2*10^25))]]
```

> `1/E^500000000000000000000000000`

It should now be evident to you why you are getting underflow with the 4th power, but not with the square.

Comment: Honestly, the `10^25` and `10^15` just look like a bad choice of units on the OP's part...

Comment: @J.M. Absolutely agree. Scaling is the solution. But that was already covered in the comments. I post this because I want the OP to see the immense numeric effect of the 4th power, and how easy it is to use Mathematica to illuminate the issue.

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for your help!
Unfortunately it wasn't easy to scale the problem because that was just a code that I had to add and match to another old program, and scaling all that code would have been too long!

Just for the sake of completeness, the correct value for the denominator was ~(2*10^48): by using it the program works perfectly!